# Get point layer stats for corresponding pixels? QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a raster.

I have a point layer.

The point layer is a line of points and where the two overlap, there are multiple points overlapping each pixe.

I want the mean and standard deviation of the points for each corresponding pixel. I.e. I want to know the pixel value, mean point value and standard deviation point value at each pixel location.

I cannot find a tool to do this? I suppose it is like 'join attributes by location (summary)' where joining to pixels rather than polygons.

Comment: Try the point sampling tool plugin

Comment: I dont understand what your point layer is. If there are multiple points in the same pixel you will get the same statistics for all the points inside it. You want the stats for each "line of points"? Can you add a screenshot showing your data?

Comment: I want the stats for the points within a pixel - there are multiple points within a pixel with different values, I want a mean and SD value for each pixel from the points.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a 2 steps methods that can answer your question with Qgis :

1. You go in Qgis toolbox and use "Raster Sampling point tools" with your raster and your point layer.

This will make a new point layer with the value of the raster on each point.

2. Then you use agregate function with some SQL queries to look for any combination of stats you would like to have (AVG, group by ) from this new layer.